# 2D search radius in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been looking into elasticsearch for a new project but i've noticed that the geo search seems exclusively for finding things on a sphere.

Is there a way to search within a radius on a 2d plane rather than 3d, I've seen that you can search using the planar option but that is still assuming a lat and log, i want to do the same thing with x and y only.

For example mongodb supports this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-a-2d-index/

Comment: Well, the geo search is about searching on a sphere after all :-)

Comment: That's for sure, but there doesn't seem to be anything for 2d.